# Перевернуть слова в массиве не меняя порядка слов JS

Tags: javascript

У меня есть массив с элементами string. Мне нужно поменять буквы в словах местами, оставив порядок слов в массиве без изменений.

Comment: массив надо заменить, потом переставлять что-там буквы, напиши код который это делает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let array = ['какой-то', 'набор', 'слов'];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i] = array[i].split('').reverse().join('');
}

console.log(array);
```

Или как предложил **yar85** используя метод [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
let array = ['какой-то', 'набор', 'слов'];

array = array.map(s => [...s].reverse().join(''));

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Код работает, спасибо.

Comment: Короткий вариант: `array = array.map(s => [...s].reverse().join(''));`